# How to tell if spark-submit has succesfully run?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any way to tell if it ran without any exceptions or completed the job? The only think I have found is this https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1788

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spark RESTful API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) to query for your application status:

1. Base URL of Spark History Server is: http://:18080/api/v1
2. List applications with `/applications`
3. Check status of your application

If the names are distinct it's quite easy to check what application is your application, even on shared cluster. You can also log `sparkContext.applicationId` and use it directly in call to Web Service